# When using par(mfrow=c(2,1)) the graphs are not shown while being created

Tags: r, graph

I'm using Rstudio and I can't save the plots and at the same time see them while they are being created on the window or plot pane. If I run line by line:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
hist(cars$dist)
hist(cars$dist, breaks=10)
hist(cars$dist, main="1920's Vehicles", xlab="Stopping Distance")
```

the graphs are created and are being shown one by one on the plot pane, but when I add the option to save the file they don't show up when I run line by line. The file is saved correctly, but why can't I see them as usual?

```
jpeg(file="results/whatever.jpeg")
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
hist(cars$dist)
hist(cars$dist, breaks=10)
hist(cars$dist, main="1920's Vehicles", xlab="Stopping Distance")
```

Thanks!

Here it shows what I want to see, and it only happens when I skip the line that saves the plot:

[image]

Comment: `dev.off()` closes the active device; usually you probably plot in the `RStudioGD` device, and if you close it the plot is gone. If you open `jpg`, which is also a device, `dev.off()` concludes the file saving process. Try running `dev.list()` in between which will make this more clear. If all is messed up, `graphics.off()` will close all devices.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem on base R or RStudio using your code but replacing the `hist()` calls with `hist(sample.int(100, 100, replace=TRUE))` twice. Both plots are present in the file.

Comment: Hi @jay.sf and thanks! The problem is not that the plot is closed with dev.off(), the problem is that it nevers shows up when adding the line to save the file. I edited my question to add that I'm using Rstudio and to use an example that can be replicated. My bad.

Comment: Hi @dcarlson and thanks too! I added the example that can be replicated. I don't understand what you mean by "both plots are present in the file". Like I said, the files are saved correctly but what I don't know is how to modify my code so I can see the plots in the window or plot pane as usual.

Comment: @AdrianaVelasquez Thanks for the nice example, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple once you have played through it.

First close all devices that may be open.

```
graphics.off()
```

Now device list should be empty.

```
dev.list()
# NULL
```

From this point, when we use `par`, `plot`, `hist` or probably any graphics related function, a device is opened.

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 2))

dev.list()  ## check
# RStudioGD       png 
#         2         3
```

Voilá, if you are using RStudio `RStudioGD` and `png` now are open devices! They are shown with their ID.

Not exactly sure why RStudio opens two devices (in contrast, e.g. VScode opens only one `pdf` device), but our current device is:

```
dev.cur()
# RStudioGD
#         2
```

Now we usually plot exactly in this device which may be considered as preview device.

```
hist(cars$dist)
hist(cars$dist, breaks=10)
hist(cars$dist, main="1920's Vehicles", xlab="Stopping Distance")
```

If we now would use `dev.off()`, the device is closed and the (preview) plot gone.

When we use a different device such as `jpeg`, `pdf`, `png`, and `postscript`, it's a little different. Here we *need* to close the device so that the plot is saved.

```
jpeg(file="whatever.jpeg")  ## open device

dev.list()  ## check
# jpeg 
#    2 

par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
hist(cars$dist)
hist(cars$dist, breaks=10)
hist(cars$dist, main="1920's Vehicles", xlab="Stopping Distance")

dev.off()  ## close device and save jpeg
```

Note: And as I said, if for some reason you end up with a lot of open devices, you can close them all at once using `graphics.off()`.

In summary, either you use the preview device or the jpeg device. So you can't have both happenning at the same time.

Comment: Hi! yes, I have to close it in order for it to be saved, but me question is why the graphs are not being shown while you run line by line when you add the line to save it! Look at this example if I skip the line to save that I added in my question. But I think what you aswered could be super useful for someone that doesn't know that you have to close the device for it to be saved.

Comment: @Because you're using the `jpeg` device and not the preview device.

Comment: @jai.sf yes...thanks, but how do I fix it in the code? Or you mean there's no way to use the device that saves and at the same time the one that shows the preview?

Comment: @AdrianaVelasquez Either you use the preview device or e.g. the `jpeg` device. The latter just saves the file without preview, but you can open the file of course. Actually using a different device than the preview device is better, because it's more stable since you may define the image size, which prevents distortion of labels, legends, and such sort of things. In Linux you may keep the jpeg (or png, pdf, ...) open and it's being updated; not sure, though, which OS you're using. Does that make sense?